# Draw margin boxes on page

Tags: page, layout

I'm trying to make sure the book has enough margin space for printing.  The minimum margins are

```
Top: 0.5”
Bottom: 0.5”
Left: 0.5”
Right: 0.5”
Gutter: 0.3”
```

I don't want to use these margins for the book (most of the time, the margins I am using are much bigger than these), but I want to make sure I have at least this amount.  Is there a way to draw a box around each page with the above dimensions, so that I can check to see if each page falls within the requirements?  I am using

```
\documentclass[A4paper,10pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in]{geometry}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try to add `showframe` to geometry settings. For example: `\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}`

Comment: If I understand this correctly, your current settings already violate the constraints as the (currently symmetric) horizontal margins are somewhat smaller than `0.5"+0.3"`.

Comment: Once you have fixed this, you can use `\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\ifodd\value{page}
 \draw[red,dashed] ([xshift=0.8in,yshift=0.5in]current page.south west)
 rectangle ([xshift=-0.5in,yshift=-0.5in]current page.north east);
\else
 \draw[red,dashed] ([xshift=0.5in,yshift=0.5in]current page.south west)
 rectangle ([xshift=-0.8in,yshift=-0.5in]current page.north east);
\fi 
\end{tikzpicture}}`.

Comment: Schrödinger - thanks, that looks nice.  You're right.  I was worried about the book's inner margins.  The others are fine.  How do you recommend I adjust it?  I need a 6' x 9' page book.  Otherwise, I was just relying on latex's default settings.

Comment: My *A Few Notes on Book Design* (`texdoc memdesign`) gives many examples of page layouts. Maybe this might be helpful in your design.

Comment: Thanks, Peter.  I'll check it out.  I changed that inner margin with [bindingoffset=.3in] and now I have widows to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

I used a partially transparent rectangle for the gutter.  The red frame are your limits.  The black frame is from geometry.

This takes two runs to work (remember picture stores the tikzpicture origin in the aux file).

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\newcommand\drawframe{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[red] ($(current page.south west)+(0.5in,0.5in)$) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(-0.5in,-0.5in)$);
    \draw[red, line width=0.3in, opacity=0.5] (current page text area.south)--(current page text area.north);
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\AddEverypageHook{\drawframe}% easier to debug separately

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```